# How does a Neural Network remember its training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The [following source code](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/) is for training a Neural Network in Python:

```
# Visualize training history
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("file.txt", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:, 0:8]
Y = dataset[:, 8]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.33, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
# list all data in history
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Where does the neural network save its memory when this training is done?

If it doesn't how can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the model with:

```
model.save('saved_model/my_model')
```

and load the model with:

```
import tensorflow as tf
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model

Answer (score 0):

You can save the whole model, like Kerrim said. Furthermore you can save the weights of the neural network with ```
model.save_weights

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize
```